# Async Await and Task.Run issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I need to know are there any differences in these records and if so, what are they?
It`s quite difficult for me:

```
1) Task.Run(async () => { await CheckVerification(); });
2) Task.Run(() => CheckVerification());
3) await Task.Run(async () => { await CheckVerification(); });
```

Comment: FYI: none of those options are correct. Most commonly you'd use `await CheckVerification();`, and in some special cases `await Task.Run(() => CheckVerification());`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto. Hi. If I don`t want to wait result. I need to just create task and return OK for user. And this task will works like background?

Comment: Then you want just `CheckVerification()`, the only correct fire-and-forget option

Comment: What do you think each of them do?  Do you know what each of the underlying operations performed in these expressions are doing?  If no, which ones do you not understand?  Have you researched what each of those operations are and what they do?  What did you not understand or find confusing or contradictory in that research?

Comment: All of these methods create 1 additional, unnecessary task. Use `Task.Run` for CPU bound work only.

Comment: 1. *Starts* a task returns immediately. The task itself awaits an async method. 2. Also *starts* a task returns immediately. The task executes a sync method. 3. Starts a tasks and waits until the task has completed. The task itself does the exact same thing as in 2.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if `CheckVerification()` is async method then your `await Task.Run(() => CheckVerification());` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mm8 Given that the method is the same method in all examples, it seems pretty safe to say that `CheckVerification` is not in fact a synchronous method.  It's awaited in other context, so it's returning an awaitable.

Comment: @mm8 Your comment on number 2 does not reflect the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__, if you pass a `Func<Task>` it should be all asynchronous

Comment: @xneg So you are saying that Microsoft provides a `Task.Run` overload that takes a `Func<Task>` that should not be used? There are legitimate uses for that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I mean I would say that.  They added it because passing an asynchronous method to `Task.Run` is almost certainly a bug, and improper design.  MS made it so that rather than returning a `Task<Task>`, which is very likely to cause confusion to people in which they await the first task and don't realize the inner task isn't complete, it gets unwrapped for them.  This turns a mistake from a broken program to a program that just has some extra overhead, but a the cost that the programmer is unlikely to notice it and fix it, or even think it's correct to do it in general.

Comment: If CheckVerification() is an async method and it's not awaited, it will return once it hits the first await.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry, my mistake. But it simplified to `Task.Run(CheckVerification)`

Comment: Thank you all. I got the idea that I create one extra task. For my fire-and-forget I`ll use just CheckVerification().

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The second overload accepts an Action.

Comment: @alexparshyn You're actually creating *two* extra tasks in several of these examples, for a total of three.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to understand the difference if we forget about `Task.Run` for a second. The difference between your 1st and 2nd points is basically the same as awaiting or just returning an inner task from a `Task` returning method:

```
// 1)
public async Task WithAwait() => await SomeOtherTaskReturningMethod();

// 2)
public Task WithoutAwait() => return SomeOtherTaskReturningMethod();
```

The first one creates another task, which wraps the inner one, which is a small overhead but otherwise these two methods are functionally *almost* identical. A small difference is when `SomeOtherTaskReturningMethod` throws an exception, then the inner task's `AggregatedException` will be unwrapped, and the (first) inner exception will be thrown further. Of course, things still depend on what happens to the external task. In your 3rd point it is also awaited so you will get the unwrapped exception from the outer task (if any), while the 1st and 2nd examples are just fire and forget.

Now let's consider `Task.Run` again. The main question why does this method have overloads, which accept `Task`s (actually `Task` returning callbacks), when you can also simply call `await CheckVerification();` and get the same result? (I know it was not part of the question but it may worth to clarify this)

So the reason of such `Task.Run` overloads exist is that a `Task` returning method itself is not necessarily executed on another thread (I suggest [this reading](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)). For example, it can just send a message through a network socket and returning a `Task`, which will be completed when a specific answer is received. This makes the operation async, still not multi-threaded.

If you have such a task and you want force it to be executed on another thread, then you can execute it by `Task.Run`, which uses the default scheduler and executes your task on a pool thread eventually.

It is worth to mention though, that this is quite a rare scenario. In most cases you should rely on the internal implementation of the `Task` returning methods.

**TL;DR:**

So I think the real question is whether

```
await CheckVerification();
```

or

```
await Task.Run(() => CheckVerification());
```

is the better solution (or maybe one of them without `await`, which is fire and forget mode). In most cases I would vote for the first one but if you are really confident that the task returned by `CheckVerification` must be assigned to a pool thread (regardless whether it does that inside or not), then the second option also can be justified.

Answer (score -1):

1) Starts a task. That task will wait for the method within, but asynchronously, so your UI or calling thread won't block.

2) Starts a task, which starts another task. Everything runs asynchonously, nothing gets awaited, completely fire and forget.

3) Will start a task, that task starts a method and awaits it, giving back execution context, letting the calling thread give away the execution context with its await, letting the method calling this continue execution until it comes to awaiting this method.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 are completely fire-and-forget operations

Comment: All of the expressions are asynchronous, so #1 is not describing a difference between any of the things, it applies to all of them.  As mentioned, #2 is not the only fire and forget option listed #3, there are also numerous differences between each of these not listed here.